# Wie nennt man die Eigenschaft, Dinge als persönlichen Angriff zu verstehen?

Tags: single-word-request

Dabei geht es nicht um Dünnhäutigkeit oder Sensibilität, sondern um den Aspekt, dass neutrale Kommentare/Aussagen oder freundlich gemeinte Verbesserungsvorschläge als persönlicher Angriff verstanden werden und eine starke emotionale und defensive Reaktion hervorrufen.

Das gesuchte Wort wäre vermutlich ein Antonym zu "kritikfähig". Gesucht ist ein Substantiv oder Adjektiv.

Comment: Paranoia? ... ;-)

Comment: Vermutlich nicht *genau* das, was du suchst, aber https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_Snowflake könnte hier eine Erwähnung wert sein...

Comment: Die Frage ist unredlich gestellt. Zuerst ist die Rede von neutralen Kommentaren, dann freundlichen Verbesserungsvorschlägen, aber am Ende geht es doch um Kritik(fähigkeit). *Nicht kritikfähig* ist ausgeschlossen, weil es mehr als ein Wort ist. *Dünnhäutigkeit* und *Empfindlichkeit*, die Wörter, an die die meisten Muttersprachler bei einem nicht kritikfähigen Individuum zuerst denken würden, sind ohne Begründung ausgeschlossen. Am Ende bleibt, wie die höchstbewertete Antwort zeigt, nur Pathologisierung übrig: *Paranoid, geisteskrank, gestört.*

Comment: @DavidVogt Dass nur noch pathologisierende Wörter übrig bleiben, ist nicht die Schuld der Frage, sondern vermutlich der deutschen Sprache, die dafür kein Wort bereithält. Es sei den jemand fällt noch was ein.

Comment: "nicht um Dünnhäutigkeit oder Sensibilität, sondern um den Aspekt, dass neutrale Kommentare/Aussagen oder freundlich gemeinte Verbesserungsvorschläge als persönlicher Angriff verstanden werden" - beschreibt Letzteres nicht recht gut Ersteres? Ich meine, ist jemand etwas dünnhäutig, dann macht ihm eine negative Aussage ziemlich zi schaffen, und ist jemand sehr dünnhäutig, dann trifft das eben sogar auf Aussagen zu, die nicht einmal negativ gemeint waren.

Comment: Ich bin nicht sicher, ob es dafür ein einzelnes Substantiv oder Adjektiv gibt, das einigermaßen verbreitet wäre. Meiner Erfahrung nach wird das beschriebene Verhalten meist mit dem Ausdruck "etwas persönlich nehmen" beschrieben.

Comment: Kritikgfähig setzt vorallem auch die Fähigkeit vorraus, Kritik zu üben. Jemand der ***selbtkritisch*** jegliche Kritik auf sich münzt versucht im prinzip nur das Argument nachzuvollziehen. Das Negativ von *kritikfähig* wäre über En *hypocrit* meines Erachtens in *Heuchelei* o.ä. zu suchen. Das ist auch ca komplementär zu *sensibel*. Allerdings passt *überkritischer Zustand* im physikalischen Sinne bzgl. Instabilität eher zu einer Kernschmelze (sofern *defensiv* die *Vorwärtsverteidigung* inbegriffen ist). Alles in allem ist hier aber nicht psych.SE

Answer (score 5):

Als alter Jan-Tenner-Fan muss ich da natürlich zuerst an

> Mimose

denken.

Answer (score 2):

Zieht man die Eigenschaft etwas weniger stark ins Krankhafte, könnte man sie

> überempfindlich

nennen, was quasi dünnhäutiger als dünnhäutig wäre.

Answer (score 1):

Aus psychologischer Sicht wäre das vielleicht zu beschreiben mit [paranoider Kritikunfähigkeit:](https://www.netdoktor.de/krankheiten/paranoide-persoenlichkeitsstoerung/)

> Typisch für die paranoide Persönlichkeitsstörung ist, dass die Betroffenen auf Kritik überempfindlich reagieren und für Misserfolge in ihrem Leben stets andere Personen verantwortlich machen. In der Schule ist es der Lehrer, der an den schlechten Noten schuld ist, im Berufsleben der Chef, wenn etwas nicht wie erwartet läuft. Aufgrund ihrer argwöhnischen und feindseligen Art sind sie bei anderen unbeliebt und streiten sich häufig mit ihren Mitmenschen. Da sie auch Freunden nicht vertrauen, haben sie kaum soziale Kontakte.

Da das allerdings in alltagssprachlichen Situationen fast gleichlautend mit einer fachlichen Diagnose wäre, sollte man diesen Begriff nicht eben leichtfertig im alltäglichen, beruflichen Umgang verwenden. Als diplomierter Küchenpsychologe käme man aber auch *mit* einer solchen korrekt gestellten Diagnose nicht an die Ursache des Problems oder zu seiner Behebung.

> [Paranoide Persönlichkeitsstörung](https://www.neurologen-und-psychiater-im-netz.org/psychiatrie-psychosomatik-psychotherapie/erkrankungen/persoenlichkeitsstoerungen/krankheitsbilder/)
> Menschen mit paranoider Persönlichkeitsstörung sind misstrauisch, abwartend und immer darauf gefasst, von anderen angegriffen oder verletzt zu werden. Auf Kritik reagieren sie überempfindlich und zeigen übertriebene und unangemessene Reaktionen in Konflikten oder Streitigkeiten. Fühlen sie sich benachteiligt oder angegriffen, gehen paranoide Persönlichkeiten zum Gegenangriff über. Gleichzeitig können diese Menschen Situationen gut analysieren und haben einen scharfsinnigen Verstand.
> Die paranoide Persönlichkeitsstörung ist selten (1% der Bevölkerung). Sie muss von wahnhaften Störungen mit Verfolgungswahn abgegrenzt werden.

Obwohl Vorstufen davon im Berufsleben gefördert werden:

> Das schlägt in extrem ängstlichen oder bisweilen aggressiven Verhalten anderen gegenüber nieder. Paranoia hat viele verschiedene Gesichter, beispielsweise reagieren die Betroffenen übermäßig sensibel auf Zurückweisung und Kritik. Auch Kränkungen und übergroßes Misstrauen sind Teil des Krankheitsbildes.
>
> Typischerweise lassen sich die Betroffenen trotz eindeutiger Fakten und Überprüfbarkeit bestimmter Sachverhalte nicht vom Gegenteil überzeugen, sondern glauben unbeirrbar an ihrer Wahrnehmung
> [Karrierebibel: Paranoia: Laut Studie eine Erfolgseigenschaft](https://karrierebibel.de/paranoia/)

Comment: Warum die Pathologisierung?

Answer (score 1):

Ich kenne so einen Menschen und finde schwer Worte für ihn;

> Ich-Bezogenheit

schwingt für mich mit.

Comment: Ich könnte das gut auf mich selbst beziehen und würde *ego-zentrisch* vorschlagen, aber da ist es quasi schon. Welch Ironie!